# Android Instrumentation Tests taking too long on a Physical Device

Tags: android

When running Android Instrumentation tests on android studio they take forever, however when I run it on a virtual device it finishes quite quickly. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm having the same issue and I'm not sure if I will be able to help but I have a few questions. What version of Android Studio are you running? What version of Gradle are you using? What version of the Android Gradle Plugin are you using? If you have already figured out the issue would you mind posing an answer? Thanks.

Comment: Hello I haven't figured out a solution yet. My Gradle version is 8.0 and I'm using android Studio Flamingo